# Akamai CDN Issue with URL Query Parameter

Tags: amazon-s3, cdn, akamai

I am working on a client project, where the AKAMAI CDN has configured. They got Amazon S3 for hosting.

**Problem**:

- I've committed the code in branch and could see the changes deployed on server in a codebase
- Now I am trying to hit server URL in browser and trying to verify my code change

  - I couldn't see the UI change as per
  - I observer the CSS file URL is coming with query parameter (i.e.: `server.com/css/filename.css??browserId=other&themeId=AbcTheme_WAR_abctheme&?t=125786954258&languageId=en_US&b=8569&t=1259648753695`)
- Now I am opening same URL in browser but now removing url query parameters from the file

  - This time I could see my changes in the same file

**Questions**:

1. Is this an issue related to CDN?
2. Is the CDN managing different versions of the same file to be served?
3. If so my changes should be merged into the latest file pointing to a webpage, which has url query parameters.
4. I know CDN will take time to refresh the pages but I am trying to verify my changes after 48 hours of the deployment.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: CloudFront isn't "hosting."  CloudFront is a CDN.  Please clarify the topology.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, sorry that's Amazon S3.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The query string you're showing seems unusual if the site is hosted on S3, since all of those would be ignored by S3.  It might serve a purpose, but S3 is only static storage, and I'm not convinced yet that this file is being served by S3.  Can you show is the response headers you receive when fetching this URL?